# Claim about counting inversions using Merge Sort

Tags: algorithms

I had a problem from the book

> Give an algorithm that determines the number of inversions in any permutation on n elements in $O(n \lg n)$ worst-case time. (Hint: Modify merge sort.)

I couldn't solve it and decided to take a hint. So there's a claim that is proved, but I don't understand this.

> To start, let us define a merge-inversion as a situation within the execution of merge sort in which the MERGE procedure, after copying $A[p..q]$ to $L$ and $A[q + 1..r]$ to $R$, has values $x$ in $L$ and $y$ in $R$ such that $x$>$y$. Consider an inversion $[i,j]$, and let $x=A[i]$ and $y=A[j]$, so that $i < j$ and $x > y$. We claim that if we were to run merge sort, there would be exactly one merge-inversion involving $x$ and $y$. To see why, observe that the only way in which array elements change their positions is within the MERGE procedure. Moreover, since MERGE keeps elements within $L$ in the same relative order to each other, and correspondingly for $R$, the only way in which two elements can change their ordering relative to each other is for the greater one to appear in $L$ and the lesser one to appear in $R$. Thus, there is at least one merge-inversion involving $x$ and $y$. To see that there is exactly one such merge-inversion, observe that after any call of MERGE that involves both $x$ and $y$, they are in the same sorted subarray and will therefore both appear in $L$ or both appear in $R$ in any given call thereafter. Thus, we have proven the claim.

By the way, $L$ and $R$ are arrays. Could someone please explain why there's exactly one merge-inversion? 
For example, $L$ is $[1, 3, 5, 7]$ and $R$ is $[2, 4, 6, 8]$ there are 6 inversions. Why does the author say about exactly one?

I will add any details if something is not clear.

Comment: The idea is, given a split into $L$ and $R$, either $i,j$ are both in $L$ or both in $R$, in which case we consider the merge subproblem for either of those subarrays, or $i$ is in $L$ and $j$ in $R$. That shows that there is at least one inversion. And, via the process of merge sort, the author shows that these elements are exchanged at most once.

Comment: Honestly, I don't like this explanation all that much. I would instead just think about how to co-opt the work you do in merge sort to count inversions. That just makes a lot more sense in my head.

Comment: @DonThousand Thanks for the reply. Yes, it's going to be done. As I understand this is just an introduction to the solution. It's very important to understand all these statements and conclusions for me, because I'm trying to improve my math skills.

Comment: @DonThousand ok, so does this claim mean that for some two items i and j can be only one merge-inversion? We can have more than one for the whole array, but for i and j indexes only one. Is that correct?